# What is the best query to sample from Impala for a huge database?

Tags: random, impala, nosql

I have a huge table (more than 1 billion rows) in Impala. I need to sample  ~ 100,000 rows several times. What is the best to query sample rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jeff mentioned, what you've asked for exactly isn't possible yet, but we do have an internal aggregate function which takes 200,000 samples (using reservoir sampling) and returns the samples, comma-delimited as a single row. There is no way to change the number of samples yet. If there are fewer than 200,000 rows, all will be returned. If you're interested in how this works, see the [implementation of the aggregate function and reservoir sampling structures](https://github.com/cloudera/Impala/blob/cdh5-trunk/be/src/exprs/aggregate-functions.cc#L821).

There isn't a way to 'split' or explode the results yet, either, so I don't know how helpful this will be.

For example, sampling trivially from a table with 8 rows:

```
> select sample(id) from functional.alltypestiny
+------------------------+
| sample(id)             |
+------------------------+
| 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 |
+------------------------+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 4.05s
```

(For context: this was added in a past release to support histogram statistics in the planner, which unfortunately isn't ready yet.)

Answer (score 1):

Impala does not currently support TABLESAMPLE, unfortunately. See https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1924 to follow its development.

Answer (score 1):

In retrospect, knowing that TABLESAMPLE is unavailable, one could add a field "RVAL" (random 32-bit integer, for instance) to each record, and sample repeatedly by adding "where RVAL > x and RVAL < y", for appropriate values of x and y.  Non-overlapping intervals [x1,y1], [x2,y2],... will be independent.  You can also select using "where RVAL%10000 = 1, =2, ... etc, for a separate population of independent subsets.

Answer (score 1):

TABLESAMPLE mentioned in other answers is now available in newer versions of impala (>=2.9.0), see [documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_tablesample.html).

Here's an example of how you could use it to sample 1% of your data:

```
SELECT foo FROM huge_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(1)
```

or

```
SELECT bar FROM huge_table TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(1) WHERE name='john'
```

Looks like `percentage` argument must be an integer, so the smallest sample you can take is limited to 1%.

Keep in mind that the proportion of sampled data from the table is not guaranteed and may be greater than the specified percentage (in this case more than 1%). This is explained in greater detail in Impala's documentation.

Comment: This is not working. When i used SYSTEM(1) parameter. The result was roughly %7.4 of the original data set not %1. Looks like a random sampling.

Comment: @math_law Why are you downvoting my answer then? It's not my fault that it was implemented this way. If you read Impala's documentation you would find out that the percentage number is not guaranteed to be exact.

Anyway, I amended my answer and added a clause warning other people about it.

Comment: I think your answer is partly still missleading. `TABLESAMPLE` samples the files of a table, *not the records*. Anyhow, since the system is heavily dependent on the no. of files which increases with large tables (at least should) and OPs question was specifically about this, it may hold for this specific case being able to somehow aprroximate the given percentage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for sample over certain column(s), you can check below answer.
Say, you have global data and you want to pick 10% from them randomly and create  your dataset. You can use any combination of columns too - like city, zip code and state.

```
select * from 
(
  select  
  row_number() over (partition by country order by country , random()) rn,
  count() over (partition by country order by country) cntpartition,
  tab.*
  from   dat.mytable tab
)rs
where rs.rn between 1 and cntpartition* 10/100  -- This is for 10% data
```

Link -
[Randomly sampling n rows in impala using random() or tablesample system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68259133/randomly-sampling-n-rows-in-impala-using-random-or-tablesample-system/68264840#68264840)