# Randomly sampling n rows in impala using random() or tablesample system()

Tags: select, impala

I would like to randomly sample n rows from a table using Impala. I can think of two ways to do this, namely:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT <n>
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM(1) limit <n>
```

In my case I set n to 10000 and sample from a table of over 20 million rows. If I understand correctly, the first option essentially creates a random number between 0 and 1 for each row and orders by this random number.
The second option creates many different 'buckets' and then randomly samples at least 1% of the data (in practice this always seems to be much greater than the percentage provided). In both cases I then select only the 10000 first rows.

**Is the first option reliable to randomly sample the 10K rows in my case?**

**Edit:** some aditional context. The structure of the data is why the random sampling or shuffling of the entire table seems quite important to me. Additional rows are added to the table daily. For example, one of the columns is `country` and usually the incoming rows are then first all from country A, then from country B, etc. For this reason I am worried that the second option would maybe sample too many rows from a single country, rather than randomly. Is that a justified concern?

Related thread that reveals the second option: [What is the best query to sample from Impala for a huge database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521853/what-is-the-best-query-to-sample-from-impala-for-a-huge-database)

Comment: If you have a nominal distribution like the countries you want to take care of try rather to do a stratified sampling instead of a pure random one.

Answer (score 2):

I beg to differ OP. I prefer second optoin.
First option, you are assigning values 0 to 1 to all of your data and then picking up first 10000 records. so basically, impala has to process all rows in the table and thus the operation will be slow if you have a 20million row table.
Second option, impala randomly picks up rows from files based on percentage you provide. Since this works on the files, so return count of rows may different than the percentage you mentioned. Also, this method is used to compute statistics in Impala. So, performance wise this is much better and correctness of random can be a problem.

Final thought -
If you are worried about randomness and correctness of your random data, go for option 1. But if you are not much worried about randomness and want sample data and quick performance, then pick second option. Since Impala uses this for `COMPUTE STATS`, i pick this one :)

EDIT : After looking at your requirement, i have a method to sample over a particular field or fields.

We will use window function to set rownumber randomly to each country group. Then pick up 1% or whatever % you want to pick up from that data set.
This will make sure you have data evenly distributed between countries and each country have same % of rows in result data set.

```
select * from 
(
  select  
  row_number() over (partition by country order by country , random()) rn,
  count() over (partition by country order by country) cntpartition,
  tab.*
  from   dat.mytable tab
)rs
where rs.rn between 1 and cntpartition* 1/100  -- This is for 1% data
```

screenshot from my data -
[image: 0.2% data from my dataset]

HTH

Comment: I edited the question with more context, explaining why the randomness part is important to me and how the data I sample from is structured. Would you still go for the second option?

Comment: I think i found a solution for you... it will sample over country data.